# Trigger Discipline Perk - Good for Snipers without VATS?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I started to play a sniper but I won't use Vats.

I heard, that a shot with a sniper rifle hits exactly where you aim. If that's true, the perk "Trigger Discipline" would be completely useless for me, right? Moreover a disadvantage, because of the lower fire rate.

Answer (score 3):

High accuracy reduces bullet spread, but [sniper rifles](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sniper_rifle_%28Fallout:_New_Vegas%29) have very little spread when you fulfill its Strength/Guns requirements. They also have a good fire rate for a long range weapon, so you might prefer not to get this perk, which is better on weapons with high spread, like shotguns.

Just note that Fallout is not exactly a shooting game, and it might sometimes frustrate a player that chooses to avoid VATS. Think of VATS more like making the game be "turn-based" instead of a "cheat mode".

Comment: Thank you. :)
Yeah its true, but if you decide to not use it, you have loads of accuracy perks you won't need and can create a more unique character. Beside, you can go with Agility 1. Greets